# WCF Error Handling and accessing class objects

Tags: .net, wcf, error-handling

I've implemented some basic WCF error handling using IErrorHandler where I can get a stacktrace and log it, however I would also like to log some other information from the class that caused the exception as well.

For example say I have the following class in my service:

```
Class Foo
    Public User As String
    Public PhoneNumber As String

    Public Function Bar() As Boolean
        Dim c As Collection 'intentionally not set to an object to cause an error below
        c.Add(PhoneNumber)
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

and I'm catching errors in:

```
  Public Function HandleError(ByVal [error] As System.Exception) As Boolean Implements ystem.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler.HandleError
        'Log ex.tostring to event log
         'How can I access User and PhoneNumber?
        Return False
    End Function
```

I now have the stacktrace of the error.  But how can I get access to User and PhoneNumber? While the stacktrace is helpful, having references to the underlying data that caused the error is paramount in an error reporting system.

Answer (score 5):

I do something similar, but I don't log the method call parameters in my `IErrorHandler` extension point. Instead, I ended up implementing a custom `IOperationInvoker` and handling parameter logging there instead.Here is a code snippet that might be useful:

```
public class MyOperationBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // intentionally empty.
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        // intentionally empty.
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        // create a name for this operation for logging purposes.
        string operationName;
        if (operationDescription.SyncMethod != null)
            operationName = operationDescription.SyncMethod.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + operationDescription.Name;
        else if (operationDescription.BeginMethod != null)
            operationName = operationDescription.BeginMethod.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + operationDescription.Name;
        else operationName = operationDescription.Name;

        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new MyOperationInvoker(operationName, dispatchOperation.Invoker);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        // intentionally empty.
    }
}
```

.

```
public class MyOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    private readonly IOperationInvoker defaultInvoker;
    private readonly string operationName;

    public MyOperationInvoker(string operationName, IOperationInvoker defaultInvoker)
    {
        if(defaultInvoker == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("DefaultInvoker can not be null.");

        this.defaultInvoker = defaultInvoker;
        this.operationName = operationName;
    }

    public object[] AllocateInputs()
    {
        return defaultInvoker.AllocateInputs();
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        Exception error = null;

        DoMySuperAwesomePreProcessing(operationName, inputs);

        try
        {
            return defaultInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex;
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            DoMySuperAwesomePostProcessing(operationName, inputs, error);
        }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronous
    {
        get { return defaultInvoker.IsSynchronous; }
    }
```

So basically it invokes whatever it normally would through the `defaultInvoker`, but before and after the call, it has an opportunity to interact with the instance, input, output, and exception if one is thrown.

At that post processing point, if I caught an error, I end up making a log of it, with the method name, and all the input parameters, and the exception method all logged, so we can try to reproduce the issue with the same inputs.

I *do* also still have a custom `IErrorHandler` implementation for logging unhandled exceptions, I just don't log the parameters from there, instead I log the parameters from the above code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an AOP tool to help with logging errors, would help to reduce the boilerplate code you would have to write to log input parameters when a method errored. [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features) works well and the free version will do what you need.

Comment: Wow that was easy!  I just added an attribute wrapper and then was able to convert args.Instance into my underlying datatype.

Comment: Also, when you are creating your AOP attribute, you might want to consider adding the *System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough* attribute to the class definition. Especially if you are using AOP to log entry and exit to methods. If you step through the injected AOP code everytime when you are debugging in visual studio it can be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless you catch the exception in the method and rethrow a custom exception with the extra information you want to log

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want your error handler to understand every type used in every operation, you should depend on exception handling in the operation itself to store any information that might be relevant to troubleshooting. In particular, the operation might know that a particular nested class structure needs to check properties for null before drilling down, but I wouldn't want to write an error handler that knows this.

Put a try/catch block around each operation for which you want to provide extra details, then throw a custom exception, including the details, and including the original exception as an InnerException.